# Elegant way to sort Array[B] for a subclass B < A, when A extends Ordered[A]?

Tags: scala, boilerplate

Having defined a class A which extends Ordering[A], and a subclass B of A, how do I automatically sort an Array of Bs?  The Scala compiler complains that it "could not find implicit value for parameter ord: Ordering[B]".  Here's a concrete REPL example (Scala 2.8), with A = Score and B = CommentedScore:

```
class Score(val value: Double) extends Ordered[Score] {
  def compare(that: Score) = value.compare(that.value)
}
defined class Score

trait Comment { def comment: String }
defined trait Comment

class CommentedScore(value: Double, val comment: String) extends Score(value) with Comment
defined class CommentedScore

val s = new CommentedScore(10,"great")
s: CommentedScore = CommentedScore@842f23

val t = new CommentedScore(0,"mediocre")
t: CommentedScore = CommentedScore@dc2bbe

val commentedScores = Array(s,t)
commentedScores: Array[CommentedScore] = Array(CommentedScore@b3f01d, CommentedScore@4f3c89)

util.Sorting.quickSort(commentedScores)
error: could not find implicit value for parameter ord: Ordering[CommentedScore]
       util.Sorting.quickSort(commentedScores)
                             ^
```

How do I fix this (that is, sort an Array[B] = Array[CommentedScore] "for free", given that I know how to sort Array[A] = Array[Score]), in an elegant manner which avoids boilerplate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add the required implicit yourself:

```
implicit val csOrd: Ordering[CommentedScore] = Ordering.by(_.value)
```

You can put this in a `CommentedScore` companion object so that there is no boilerplate at use-site.

---

Edit: if you want the ordering method to be defined only at the top of the inheritance tree, you still have to provide an `Ordering` for each subclass, but you can define the `compare` method of the `Ordering` in terms of the one in the `Score` object. i.e.

```
object Score {
  implicit val ord: Ordering[Score] = Ordering.by(_.value)
}

object CommentedScore {
  implicit val csOrd = new Ordering[CommentedScore] { 
    def compare(x: CommentedScore, y: CommentedScore) = Score.ord.compare(x, y)
  }
}
```

if you don't want to re-define this for each sub-class, you can use a generic method to produce the `Ordering`:

```
object Score {
  implicit def ord[T <: Score]: Ordering[T] = Ordering.by(_.value)
}
```

This is a bit less efficient since being a `def` rather than a `val`, it creates a new `Ordering` each time one is required. However the overhead is probably tiny. Also note, the `Ordered` trait and `compare` method is not necessary now we have `Ordering`s.

Comment: Thanks. But I'd like it to depend on the Score ordering: suppose I later refactor the Score ordering to sort by descending value instead of increasing value.  I'd like CommentedScore to inherit that change.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you very much, Luigi.  Unfortunately I'm such a newbie to Scala that I don't know what "use delegation" means.  If it's not too much trouble, would you mind demonstrating what you mean in this `Score` case?

Comment: @PerfectTiling delegation just means passing the arguments along to another method that does the real work. Have edited above.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `Order` from scalaz, which is contravariant, so you need not to define it for every subclass. Here is an example:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

class Score(val value: Double)
object Score {
  implicit val scoreOrd: Order[Score] = orderBy(_.value)
}
trait Comment { def comment: String }
class CommentedScore(value: Double, val comment: String) extends Score(value) with Comment {
  override def toString = s"cs($value, $comment)"
} 
def quickSort[E: Order](list: List[E]): List[E] = list match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: tail =>
    val (less, more) = tail partition { e => implicitly[Order[E]].order(e, head) == LT }
    quickSort(less) ::: head :: quickSort(more) 
}
println(quickSort(List(
  new CommentedScore(10,"great"),
  new CommentedScore(5,"ok"),
  new CommentedScore(8,"nice"),
  new CommentedScore(0,"mediocre")
))) // List(cs(0.0, mediocre), cs(5.0, ok), cs(8.0, nice), cs(10.0, great))
```

Comment: I'd always thought that Ordering ought to be covariant. I haven't had a chance to think it through though.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
val scoreArray: Array[Score] = Array(s, t)
util.Sorting.quickSort(scoreArray)
```

Or if you are starting from the `Array[CommentedScore]`:

```
val scoreArray: Array[Score] = commentedScores.map(identity)
util.Sorting.quickSort(scoreArray)
```

Note you can sort more simply with:

```
scoreArray.sorted
```

Comment: Thanks. In reality I'm using my own custom partial-sort algorithm on the Array.  I put util.Sorting.quickSort here in place of that.  In the end, I have to make sure I have an Array[CommentedScore], so I don't want to have to convert to Arra[Score] and then cast to Array[CommentedScore].